# macerating toilet installation with 4x90 degrees

Tags: installation, pump

I have a saniflo compact elite "temporary" or macerating toilet, and it was installed with 4x90 degree connectors on the way to the wall drain where a laundry machine once was used.

Is this ok or not ok?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably work, but is not ideal.  It will put additional strain on the pump and be prone to blockages (moreso than something with no 90's).  If there is no cleanout nearby then you have another problem: getting a snake through all of these bends to clear a blockage.  Again, this is no a "showstopper" and you *can* still clean this out, but your job is just a bit harder than it should be (that's a general plumbing issue not related to macerating toilets specifically).

A similar question is available on the [Saniflo FAQ page](https://www.saniflo.com/us/cms/3/faqs#) where they recommend against **any** 90 degree elbows...and you have four.  In the end, your question

> Is this ok>

depends on what you mean by "ok".

Will it work?  Yes.

Will it work as well as something that was plumbed correctly?  No, you will be more prone to blockages and additional wear on the pump.

Comment: thank you very much for the link and explanation